# Chapel on a starship?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, religion

Highly related to [Maggots at a party... How would alien races dine together?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/5158/2071) but hopefully not duplicate.

I am designing my own Starfleet. I want it to be original, but I know that if I want to avoid all racial and cultural misunderstanding, it will look a lot like usual Star-Trek.

Imagine, you have universe as diverse as you can imagine. And these races, humans included, want to have joint operation star ship. So far I came up with these ideas:

- Starfleet is purely scientific operation.
- All members on board go through racial diversity training and are prepared to deal with alien races
- Shifts on board are organized in a way that races who feel really "alien" to each other will meet as little as possible (example: Humans have "day" shifts while insectoids have "night" shift, so humans can eat their lunch without looking at insectoids eating their maggots)
- Speaking of which, there is definitely more than one mess hall on the ship. So far thinking about at least two mess halls, so you can eat your food in peace.
- Religion is contained to personal quarters, all members on board agree on purely atheistic manners.

But the last point gives me real head aches. For next parts I will use human religions only.

Even if some humans feel atheist, they still do celebrate religion-based holidays, like Christmas.

Moreover, humans tend to celebrate these holidays in groups and most of them generally agree that celebrating these holidays together is what brings real "spirit" to these holidays.

Also, take for granted, that religious <del>people</del> crew-members will be on board. So the question is:

**Should I design one room purposed just for religious intentions on my starship?**

Assumptions:

- Building spaceship is hard
- Bigger spaceship requires more fuel
- Fuel is hard to get
- Replicators do not exist in my universe
- [Holodecks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holodeck) are not a thing, not invented in my universe
- Faster than light travel is a thing, for scope of this question assume that "works perfectly"
- Majority of crew members on the ship will worship some religion
- Given starship will be "in the wild" for at least three human years. Some stops are granted, but there can be more than two months without possibility to leave the ship

Comment: There are books with chapels on ships, there are ones without. There are real life navies with them, there are ones without. We have the same issue in real life, and no definitive, objective answer for it despite ages of experience... how answer to your "should" can be anything but personal opinion, or, at best, opinion based on the society someone was raised in?

Comment: I feel like 90% of your question is kind of a red herring. I don't see how fuel, something about "race", Star Trek, the location of the mess hall and all of that relate to the issue. The thing is, even though you've given us a good general idea about what you want to write about, I completely fail to see the issue you have with having an all-purpose religious room or with not having such a room since ."Religion is contained to personal quarters, all members on board agree on purely ateistic manners.". I think you would greatly benefit from focusing your question around your actual question

Comment: You ship has meeting rooms - adepts of a religion can book a room for their services.

Comment: So true. I failed to check how it's done today on the sea. Will delete question in about an hour

Comment: castles had similar problems (costly to build, few space), but had chapels

Comment: They could use virtual reality to join in to whatever religious mass (or any other scheduled programme) they want. Alternately, even in our culture, digital realities like MMOs (without any virtual reality added) are so prevalent that they sort of have their own culture. I could imagine a future where religious gestures and symbolism is relegated to digital spaces like that and it is nothing out of the ordinary, even for people not on a starship.

Comment: @RealSubtle Virtual reality congregations is an excellent area. No additional physical space for venues are required.

Comment: The Enterprise had a chapel, so your ship can, too.  http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Chapel

Comment: @RealSubtle Your VR congregations concept should be the basis of an answer. It resolves all the issues of space, mass & resources allocation for a chapel. It's the best answer. Go for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Space used on vessels of any kind is dictated by *practical necessity* not by emotional needs.  Crew are going to be selected for their ability to function in a restricted and limited environment.  People who can't do that won't be selected.

> Moreover, humans tend to celebrate these holidays in groups and most of them generally agree that celebrating these holidays together is what brings real "spirit" to these holidays.

This of course is nothing to do with religion as such.  Religion is generally about personal belief and ethics and you are confusing social interaction with religious needs.

All that is required on any vessel to fulfill all these requirements is the ability to have some form of shared or common area.  On smaller vessels this is simply the entire living and working quarters as they are typically the same space.  On larger vessels there is typically a dedicated mess hall mainly used for eating, but which would be a focus for communal activity.

But ultimately crew on such a vessel are specifically selected for their ability to co-exist and maintain what private space they need entirely in their heads.

A submarine would be the best model for a spaceship of this fictional type.  Resources are small, quarters cramped and shared (down to sharing bunks on a shift basis) and common areas consist of practically nothing more than the absolute minimum needed for particular functions, like eating (in shifts).

Space for religious worship - in your head.

In relation to religious requirements you might note this video :

[Do Muslim's Face Mecca When Praying In Space ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZysBWn3yyaQ) on the *Today I Found Out* channel on YouTube.

This discusses briefly some of the complications and the official position adopted by some religions on the subject.

But the bottom line for religious space on a space ship ?  In. Your. Own. Head.

> Shifts on board are organized in a way that races who feel really "alien" to each other will meet as little as possible (example: Humans have "day" shifts while insectoids have "night" shift, so humans can eat their lunch without looking at insectoids eating their maggots)

In practical terms this (and many related issues) is why ships would almost always have single species crews, or at most crews populated by closely compatible crews.  It simply makes no sense to try and force incompatible crews together long term - it's asking for trouble.

Comment: This. It so solved my problem. Thanks a lot. Worth keeping the question open for three days to give you more reward :)

Comment: @PavelJanicek Just in case and as I'm not sure what you mean by "keep open for three days" (as you're a high rep member), but the norm is to leave open forever (accepting an answer is not closing a question).

Comment: I just had second thought about the question itself, if its "worth" keeping it here and not delete it forever. I will keep it up and after three days there is a bounty option. You deserve it for idea of submarine

Comment: It's your choice of course, but my view is that we should leave any question not voted off-topic by the community in place.  In all honesty I think my "submarine" suggestion would probably be one many posters would have thought of, I just happened to be first up.

Comment: "Religion is generally about personal belief and ethics and you are confusing social interaction with religious needs." Not so. Religions have a strong social function. They are conceptual glue for many societies. The trouble is that people in modern secular societies like those in the West often fail to understand the social, political & cultural aspects of religion. The word religion itself derives for Latin words means connecting or binding together. It's a community thing not purely individualistic.

Comment: @a4android If you are e.g. locked in solitary confinement do your religious obligations or needs stop ?  I don't think so.  If society around you stops conforming to your religion, do your religious obligations/needs stop ?  Again, I think not.  It's ultimately personal.  It's function as social glue is secondary, it's primary function is to inform and enrich the soul.  In restricted settings you can't generally rely on the secondary aspects, but the primary ones remain.

Comment: @a4android you seem to be presuming that religion is somehow necessary for community, which strikes me as bizarre. Having been raised in an entirely secular way, and living among secular people, no religion has been at all necessary for community in my society. If you meant it the other way around, that community is necessary for religion, please be more clear.

Comment: @StephenG Culture, society & religion go hand in hand. Your comment shows a lamentable lack of understanding of social forces. While there is an interplay between individual belief & cultural ideology, religion is shaped by society which in turn shapes individual beliefs, with a degree of historical inertia and path dependence affecting cultural formation.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi You presume wrongly about my position. Yes I do mean religion & community go together. Secular belief structures are the 'religion' of secular societies. It's a cultural thing. Religious belief is remarkably powerful and extremely persuasive. So much so, it's amazing secular societies have been able to arise.

Comment: @a4android We're not talking about *forming* a culture or a society, we're talking about the day-to-day religious formalities and the needs and ways they can operate in a closed environment.  Religious belief may be "remarkably powerful and extremely persuasive" to *you*, but not to me.  Choice on ship : space and mass used for provisions and vital spares or used for religious paraphernalia.  Result : religion left at door, you keep what you carry in your head.  Survival in space is defined by efficient use of physical mass, not religious mass.

Comment: @a4android you're only mystified by how secularism can survive because of your religious belief - you've placed it so central to your understanding of the world that you cannot imagine any alternative or how people can interact without it being about religion. No, "secular belief" is in no way a religion as it is a meaningless term. Religion is indeed a powerful force exploiting the flaws in human behavior, which is why it survives despite clear evidence that any rational person should rejecting such harmful superstitions.

Comment: @StephenG Religious belief isn't remarkably powerful and extremely to me. This is based on the evidence of history and psychology. Your thinking is shaped by the contemporary set of individualistic memes. I recognize people value religion, so I tolerant accordingly even if I don't share it, while you seem to see it as an optional extra. Cultural irrationality will triumph over the purely rational far too often. The VR chapel suggested in comments above was the best option.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi I could say something rude because you have made utterly erroneous assumptions. I am a secularist, however, I have enough knowledge of the social sciences to understand the role belief systems play in society. This includes religion which is only one form of community forming mechanism. 'Religion' in its broadest sense is nothing more than a sets of ideas and behaviour that bring people together. Secular beliefs do that too.

Answer (score 0):

I would just point out that when Christianity was founded, they celebrated in their homes, even when their religion was tolerated by authorities. When Christianity became a majority religion, they *generally* took over civil spaces - Romans had previously used basilicas for arguing about legal matters - and not converted temples.

I'd assume if your religious crew members are small enough in number, then they'd meet in someone's quarters. If they can't fit, and your ship has meeting rooms similar to what Alexander points out in his comment, then they might gather in one temporarily.